# Google Maps Javascript API asynchronious obtaining and dynamic displaying of markers?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Is there an example or option for displaying the google maps markers with some animation. Currently we are displaying them with loading gif like overlay over the map, but would be cool if the markers could popup dynamically on the map or have some nice animation for loading.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like [in the Google Maps API documentation example here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations-iteration)?

```js
function addMarkerWithTimeout(position, timeout) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    }));
  }, timeout);
}
```

Comment: yes it could be. I was thinking of how to make asynchronious call with ajax request to get the points from the server continuously and push them similarly.

Comment: Then you should update your question (and the title). Right now it's only asking about marker animation, which is addressed in the link.